# Alcohol as necessary medicine when visiting dry countries?

Tags: legal, health, alcohol

In hospital a few years ago, I met a man who needed to take anticoagulation medicine daily.  However, he had some sort of stomach enzyme that prevented him absorbing the medicine.  As a result, daily, an hour beforehand he'd announce he was taking his 'first medicine' and drank a glass of white wine (which the doctors had noted would inhibit the enzyme).  (excuse my medical terms, I'm relaying second hand).

Anyway, the question is - if he wants to travel to a dry (as in no alcohol) country, like Iran, or Brunei - could he, if he needs the alcohol? Would a doctor's letter be enough?

Comment: Sounds like an excuse to drink to me. Doubtful if it is real.

Comment: @Aganju I watched the doctor prescribe it to him.

Comment: @MarkMayo my wife's a doctor and she just said "bollocks".  Chances are, he just got a friendly doctor to write him a prescription allowing him a glass of wine a day while he was in hospital - my wife has done similar for patients (but they would need to supply their own alcohol - hospital pharmacies don't carry wine, beer etc but they do carry a few spirits as those *are* prescribable for conditions such as methanol poisoning). There are better enzyme inhibitors than alcohol available.

Comment: @MarkMayo note that your question is *very* similar to that of any other question involving prohibited treatments such as opiate based medications etc and travel to largely the same countries - for a good selection of such drugs, there is no exemption for carrying them and you may be prosecuted and jailed - there is no difference for the outcome in this question.

Comment: @Moo I'm not a doctor, but a quick google mentions the VKORC1 enzyme.  But we're getting away from the point.

Comment: @MarkMayo I'm not saying the enzymes don't exist, I'm saying the likelihood that a doctor would prescribe an alcoholic drink to treat it to be extreeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeemly minute, based on my wife's laughter. Also, she posted it to a closed UK doctors Facebook group and it's gaining similar hilarity based reactions there... yeah, your guy just got a doctor to allow him a glass of wine a day, that's all.

Comment: @Moo welll they can go talk to the cardiologists at the Royal Brompton in London then :)

Comment: @MarkMayo my wife has prescribed pints of beer for old chaps who were admitted longish term into hospital, so they could have their normal pint with their mates on Fridays etc, so doctors certainly do prescribe alcohol for non-medicinal purposes... the issue here is that there are plenty of anticoagulants which aren't taken orally, so there really is no need at all to go to the complexities of solving an enzyme issue in the stomach with alcohol when there are alternatives that don't need it.

Comment: Good luck getting that excuse through Saudi Customs

Comment: Any doctors/nurses/medical professionals here who know if there is a non-alcoholic option that has the same effect?  If there is, I can't see a dry country allowing alcohol when there is an alternative, unless there is some hugely material disadvantage to the alternative.  Alcohol's advantage in wet countries is that it's ubiquitous.

Comment: If a common, widely known, medical situation exists that requires alcohol to be consumed, and only that, in order to be resolved than, quite likely, yes, a doctor's letter would be enough. Also, I was quite sure that Iran and Afghanistan issue(d?) alcohol to certified alcoholics, but quick Google searches return nothing relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Whether any country will recognize the user of alcohol for medicinal purposes presumably depends on that country's medical regulators.  Dry countries might allow the user of alcohol on a foreign doctor's prescription, or they might require the prescription of a doctor licensed to practice medicine in that country, or the regulator might only approve alternative therapies (for example, to interfere with the enzyme in question) that do not involve alcohol.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the country. In Brunei for instance, non-Muslims can import twelve cans of beer and 2 bottles of liquor, every 48 hours (when doing a Labuan run for instance). You can only consume the alcohol inside your residence, hotel, etc... You won't be able to buy any in-country.

Other countries can be stricter, and it would prove dangerous to break the law. But in all muslim countries, doctor's orders won't fly, especially a foreign doctor. A person needing alcohol for medical reasons would have as much leverage as a person with a cannabis prescription in Singapore. Zilch.

Comment: Can you explain what your answer is based on, and give references if possible?  Personal experience, educated guess, published laws and guidelines, third-party articles, ...?  When an answer just has categorical statements without evidence, it tends to trigger the reaction "Why should we believe *you*?"  I would guess this is the reason for the downvotes you were complaining about.

Comment: I work in the alcohol business, especially with duty-free places like Labuan, covering Asia. So I have extensive esperience with this. But why should you believe me right.

Comment: I see.  Perhaps you could mention that in your answer?

Comment: I believe that's rather pointless, as it is an unprovable point. Negative people who spend their time downvoting instead of contributing won't be changed by this. This is getting tiring.

Answer (score 1):

If the person in question truly needs alcohol as medicine, it would be best to purchase it in a medical container rather than carrying a bottle of whiskey in your luggage. It is best to ask the doctor in your country about how to obtain medicinal alcohol, but I expect it to be packaged similar to [ethanol used for scientific research](https://www.sciencecompany.com/Ethyl-Alcohol-1-gal-200-Proof-Absolute-Undenatured-ACS-USP-Grade-P17107.aspx):

[image]

Of course, you'd still have to declare it as a medicine at each border, but I expect the border guards to be more lenient if it appears as something that could actually be used for treatment.